# La base de datos de advertencia se ha bloqueado durante 0:00:10.000000. Flutter

Tags: flutter

Buen día estoy trabjando con flutter y traigo en un modelo datos que consumi en una API para luego insertarlos a una tabla de sqlite, todo bien. Pero demora mucho y me manda la advertencia de que se a bloqueado la bd. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
// Insertar productos que recibe de la API
Future<int> insertDataProductos(Producto product) async {
  final Database db = await initDB();
  return await db.transaction((txn) async {
    return await txn.insert('productos', product.toMap());
  });
}
```

Soy principiante algun consejo o recomendación, agradezco de antemano!

Comment: Prueba dividir los datos y pasarlos de a bloques

Comment: @Yussef vi su documentacion de sqlite y vi algo sobre ello BATCH pero tengo duda de como dividir  "product" traigo 6500 y en 5538 me marca el aviso. Alguna idea perdona

Comment: Es que yo de flutter no tengo ni idea, ni sabia que existía. Pero un algoritmo básico es recorrer la lista con `for` con índice, luego estableces un número arbitrario, digamos `1000` y otra lista a modo de buffer. Dentro del for pones un `if( i%1000==0) ` y cuando cumple pasas la info del buffer a sqlite y limpias el buffer. Obviamente en cada iteración vas llenando el buffer con el item correspondiente al índice. Quizas flutter tenga un modo más elegante de hacerlo, algo como separar subarray o un sistema de paginación como `take`, pero ni idea